# Is there a way to retrieve the final number of nodes generated by sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to retrieve the final number of nodes generated by sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier if it there were no constraints on max_depth, min_samples, etc.?

Comment: Is this for 7641? :)

Comment: :-) Yes. The complexity you use is based on total nodes and that appears most appealing to me. Max_depth seems too constraining and likely to push out somewhere else - breadth-wise and maybe less desirable. Max_leaf_nodes I think is better. I'm using max_depth until I have time to redo things and test max_depth or find a way to get the max nodes. I have a way but it entails installing NLTK, which I want to do anyway, but the timing is...shall I say...off.

Comment: Yeah, I went the R route, and haven't been able to acquire the total nodes in R either, but thankful that it gives me the number of terminal nodes. Good luck!

Comment: For what class is this?

Comment: @mheller Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: Thanks again everyone. This helped me totally. What a wonderful introduction and demonstration to the value of stackoverflow and crowd sourcing generally!

Comment: I agree with Joshua Taylor on this. Accepting an answer helps improve the site. I would suggest his answer.

Answer (score 8):

### Number of nodes

Once you have the tree, you can access its internal **tree_** object, and that tree's various attributes.  One of those, described in the source, is [**node_count**](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L2967):

> #### Attributes
>
> - node_count : int
>   The number of nodes (internal nodes + leaves) in the tree.

So you can do:

```
c = DecisionTreeClassifier(…)
c.fit(…)
n_nodes = c.tree_.node_count
```

### Other attributes of nodes

Other various properties of the nodes are stored in arrays that are attributes of the tree object, and indexed by node ids.  E.g., the **value** attribute of that is an array of the node scores, and **n_node_samples** is an array of the numbers of samples at each node.   The answer by [ericmjl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28171192/1281433) goes into a bit more detail with references about that representation. You can use that to get the value for a specific node:

```
c = DecisionTreeClassifier(…)
c.fit(…)
value_i = c.tree_.value[i]
```

Comment: Pythonic! Better than my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

In part because I don't have a decision tree to work with myself, I can't provide concrete examples here. However, I think delving into the source code may help.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx

sklearn's decision tree has an attribute tree_, which is the underlying Tree object. The Tree object is defined in the _tree.pyx class. The Tree object is an:

> "Array-based representation of a binary decision tree.
>       The binary tree is represented as a number of parallel arrays. The `i`-th
>       element of each array holds information about the node `i`. Node 0 is the
>       tree's root.

Recall that there are some internal nodes in the tree, but the decision tree is always binary. So as you traverse from node 0 onwards, you can access the tree attributes `children_left` and `children_right` to figure out which nodes are children of each node. The `threshold` attribute may also be useful to you.

Some pseudocode that **may** (emphasis on may) work is:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
[... train and test...]
print(clf.tree_.node_count) #get the node count.
print(clf.tree_.children_left[node]) #where node is some integer
print(clf.tree_.children_right[node])
print(clf.tree_.threshold[node])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

**Number of "if" nodes**

I think it's more useful to calculate number of "if" nodes rather than the total nodes count.

```
from sklearn.tree import _tree
clf.fit(…)
ifs_count = len([x for x in clf.tree_.feature if x != _tree.TREE_UNDEFINED])
```