# How to get the number of leaves and nodes in a trained sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have trained a DecisionTreeClassifier and I would like to know how many leaves and nodes it has.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to retrieve the final number of nodes generated by sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160129/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-final-number-of-nodes-generated-by-sklearn-tree-d)

Comment: For 50%. It does not specify how to get the number of leaves in the question nor answers.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the internal `tree_` object:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
print('Leaves:', clf.tree_.n_leaves)
print('Leaves and Nodes:', clf.tree_.node_count)
```